# Calling activity from another app that stores data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I am currently developing a set of three standalone Apps for Android. One of these Apps provides functionality that - if this App is installed on a device - can be called by the other two apps. This specific activity collects some data and stores it in an SQLite DB. Since I am rather new to Android development I'd like to know the following:

If I call an external activity from within my App, does this activity act as if it were still part of its "originating" App and thus accesses data managed by the originating App? That's what I think is happening but I want to be sure before I design my Apps that way.

Thanks for helping out

Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I call an external activity from within my App, does this activity act as if it were still part of its "originating" App and thus accesses data managed by the originating App? That's what I think is happening but I want to be sure before I design my Apps that way.

this activity will run in its own process. This means that if its process was not yet created, then it will be created for this activity.

If you are the owner of all your apps and want them to share data you might be interested in this manifest option:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid

> android:sharedUserId
>
> The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own
> unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value
> for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID —
> provided that they are also signed by the same certificate.
> Application with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if
> desired, run in the same process.